# Need help creating a query for a non-normalized database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've never worked with a non-normalized database before, so I'll try and explain my problem as best I can.  So I have two tables:

[image]

The customers table holds all the customers information, and the orders table holds all the orders that they have placed.  I haven't listed all the fields in the tables, just the ones that I need.  The customer number in both tables is not the primary key, but I'm inner joining on them anyway.  So the problem I'm having is that I don't know how to make a query that:

Selects all the customers with their first name, last name, and email, and also show the most recent orderdate, most recent total, and most recent ordertype.  I know that I have to use a max() aggregate for the date, but that's as far as I got.  Please help a noob out.

Comment: What does "most recent" mean? Last week, month?

Comment: The very last order they have placed.

Comment: btw - what's not normalized in this data model?  you have a table for customers and a one-to-many for that customer's orders.

Comment: Well if I'm not mistaken, for this structure to be normalized, the orders table should be a bridge table, for customers and a products table.

Comment: in lay terms, normalized simply means that the same information isn't be dup'd across rows.  if there is additional order data (like hte product being ordered), the OrderType may be pointing to that information as far as we all know.  seeing just the tables you show, it isn't obviously denormalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       Email,
       OrderDate,
       OrderTotal,
       OrderType

FROM Customers AS C
INNER JOIN Order AS O
  ON O.CustomerNumber = C.CustomerNumber AND
     O.OrderDate = (
                    SELECT MAX (O1.OrderDate)
                    FROM Order AS O1
                    WHERE O1.CustomerNumber = C.CustomerNumber)
                   )
```

Comment: i bumped you up one since it's effectively the same as my answer, but with one less join.  yours may be semantically clearer too

Answer (score 2):

assuming that Orders.OrderDate is unique for each CustomerNumber, does this work for you?  if a single CustomerNumber has more than one entry in Order for OrderDate, you'll get each of those rows.

```
select c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Email, o.OrderDate, o.OrderTotal, o.OrderType
from Customers c
join
(select CusomterNumber, max(OrderDate) as MostRecentOrderDate
 from Orders
 group by CustomerNumber
) mro on mro.CustomerNumber=s.CustomerNumber
join Orders o on o.OrderDate=mro.MostRecentOrdeDate and
                 o.CustomerNumber=mro.CustomerNumber
```

Comment: There is an entry for every product they order, but the date is the same in each entry(unless they do a new order a different day)

Comment: ok - so if you want every order on the most recent day, then this should give you that.

Comment: Oh i forgot to mention that it needs be distinct.

Comment: what should be distinct?  you can use the results of this query and act on it however you want.  since it returns all data for the most recent date, you can then get a sum of order totals, the greatest order total, a list of distinct order types, etc.

Comment: Yeah the data being returned is correct, but I just wanted one entry per customer.  I added the distinct after the select and I think I'm getting what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
 Customers.*, Orders.*
FROM
 Customers
JOIN 
 (SELECT
   Customer_Number,
   MAX(Order_Date) OrderDate
  FROM
   Orders
  GROUP BY 
   Customer_Number
) as Ord ON Customers.Customer_Number = Ord.Customer_Number
JOIN Order ON Orders.Customer_Number = Ord.Customer_Number
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this with SQL Server use the query designer and basically all you want to do is do a join since you have two keys that are the same one in Customer Table ->Customer Join on Order->Customer alias the Customer table as C and Orders table as O

so for example

```
SELECT Customer.*, Orders.* 
From Customer c, Orders O INNER JOIN O where C.Customer Number = O.Customer Number
```

This should be enough to get you started.. if you don't want all the fields then  fully qualify the names for example

```
SELECT C.FirstName, C.LastName, O.OrderDate, O.OrderType FROM Customer C, Orders O 
WHERE C.Customer NUmber = O.Customer Number //this is another way of doing a Join when working with the where Clause.
```